# Why is TypeScript unable to detect mismatched types at compile time and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In our codebase we have code like below which is unable to detect if a `type violation` occurred due to programmer error - why does this happen and what's the best way to address this problem?

```
// forcing a structure on "shape" of the output
interface IPayloadOutput {
  [key: string]: string
}

interface MyPayloadOutput extends IPayloadOutput {
    myPayloadKey1: string
    myPayloadKey2: string
    extraKey: string //adding this here doesn't cause compile error if it's not returned
}

// Input data needs that to be transformed to the output
interface MyPayloadInput {
    data1: string
    data2: string
}

class MyPayloadOutputGenerator extends PayloadOutputGenerator {
    public getPayloadKeyValues(args: MyPayloadInput): IPayloadKeyValues {
        return {
            myPayloadKey1: {key1: args.data1, key2: args.data2},
            myPayloadKey2: { key1: args.data1 + '-senor' },
            // Why does code not throw compile error if the below field is missing?
            // extraKey: { key1: 'extra' }
        }
    }
}

function consumer(response: MyPayloadOutput): void {
    console.log(response)
}

const x = new MyPayloadOutputGenerator().getPayloadOutput<MyPayloadInput, MyPayloadOutput>({
    data1: 'hello',
    data2: 'wrold',
})

consumer(x) // should throw compiler error if missing `extraString`
```

The `PayloadGenerator` takes in the `Input` and transforms it into the expected `Output`. But the key `extraString` in `MyPayloadOutput` is missing in the data returned but no compiler error is reported? Why is that?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxf2Lhq7/) showing a running example

For completeness, here's the `PayloadGenerator`:

```
// all payloads need key1 and an optional key2.
interface IPayloadDetails {
    key1: string
    key2?: string
}

// force structure for how we expect payload key/values to look
interface IPayloadKeyValues {
  [key: string]: IPayloadDetails
}

abstract class PayloadOutputGenerator {

    // source keys from implementing classes. `args` is not typed to be 'anything'
    public abstract getPayloadKeyValues(args): IPayloadKeyValues

    // Generic method to be used with any input/output combo
    public getPayloadOutput<Input, Output>(args: Input): Output {
        const payloadKeyValues = this.getPayloadKeyValues(args)
        const payloadOutput = {} as Output
        Object.keys(payloadKeyValues).forEach(key => {
            payloadOutput[key] = JSON.stringify(payloadKeyValues[key]) //do custom encoding here
        })

        return payloadOutput
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You typecasted (`as Output`) and omitted Typings at central positions (`: IPayloadKeyValues`) and over all worked against typescripts type system. By using index types, you made it impossible for typescript to determine what the code actually does. Instead, use Generics from the beginning:

```
abstract class PayloadOutputGenerator<I, O extends {}> { // already introduce the generic here ...
  public abstract getPayloadKeyValues(args: I): O // then you can narrow down this correctly

  public getPayloadOutput(args: I) { // and this gets typed correctly automatically 
    const payloadKeyValues = this.getPayloadKeyValues(args);
    const payloadOutput = {} as { [K in keyof O]: string }; // its a mapped type, so lets type it as such
    Object.keys(payloadKeyValues).forEach(key => {
        payloadOutput[key] = JSON.stringify(payloadKeyValues[key]) //do custom encoding here
    });

    return payloadOutput
  }
}
```

Comment: also getPayloadOutpout takes a MyPayloadInput due to your generic but you modified the MyPayloadOutput

Comment: Interesting - yeah I thought that the typing of they `PayloadOutputGenerator` has a role to play. Any chance of working/modified fiddle?

Comment: @PhD not today, its close to midnight :)

Comment: Ha! Please get some rest. FWIW: `public abstract getPayloadKeyValues(args: I): O` doesn't work as expected with what's in the fiddle...

Comment: ....I "need" to keep the `IPayloadKeyValues` around but the modification doesn't support that IMO